# ModelState is invalid if data annotation is used on password field

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I use the standard ASP.NET Identity approach to store users. It works, the user gets stored, but if I use a regular expression data annotation on the password field, the `ModelState` is invalid. Without this annotation, the user is stored (I tried it with the same password). This is the corresponding action:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(User UserModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AppUser User = new AppUser
        {
            UserName = UserModel.Name,
            Email = UserModel.Email
        };
        IdentityResult Result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(User, UserModel.Password);
        if (Result.Succeeded)
        {
            TempData["success"] = true;
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Mode = "new";
            return PartialView("User", UserModel);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
}
```

And this is the `User` model:

```cs
public class User
{
    [Display(Name = "Felhasználó")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A mező kitöltése kötelező")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail cím")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A mező kitöltése kötelező")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\d\w\._\-]+@([\d\w\._\-]+\.)+[\w]+$", ErrorMessage = "Érvénytelen e-mail cím")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Első belépési jelszó")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A mező kitöltése kötelező")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A jelszónak minimum 6, maximum 100 karakter hosszúnak kell lennie", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)", ErrorMessage = "A jelszónak legalább 1 számot, 1 kisbetűt, 1 nagybetűt és 1 speciális karaktert kell tartalmaznia")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I have really no idea, why it works without the annotation and with it doesn't. Maybe you have one?

Comment: Maybe too silly to ask, but have you checked whether the password you enter is valid for given regular expression?

Comment: I use client side validation as well and the password is validated fine on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

My regex was wrong. With this it works as expected:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\W])[A-Za-z\d\W]{6,}$
```